# Slice array not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework

I get a list in json and put it in an array.

```
{"event_date": "2016-12-07 01:39:41","created_at": "15/11/2016 às 06:10"}
```

In this list I have a `"_date"` attribute: `"2016-12-07 01:39:41"`.
I'm trying to make a slice to get 2016 through 07.

```
$scope.getPostsDate = function() {
        PostsService.getPosts($scope.token).then(function(result) {
            var postsByDate = result.data;
            angular.forEach($scope.postsByDate, function(value, key) {
                var oldDate = value.event_date;
                value.newDate = oldDate.slice(0, 10);
                console.log('date' +value.newDate);
            })
        })
    }
```

Result:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null at posts.ctrl.js:67
Console result: date 2016-11-28
What I do not understand is that I did the same thing in another method and it worked:

```
$scope.getPosts = function() {
        PostsService.getPosts($scope.token).then(function(result) {
            $scope.posts = result.data;
            angular.forEach($scope.posts, function(value, key) {
                var str = value.created_at;
                value.data = str.slice(0, 10);
                value.hour = str.slice(11, 25);
            })
            console.log($scope.posts);
        })
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `value.event_date` is null, why is hard to answer, it's your data ?

Comment: change `var postsByDate = result.data;` to `$scope.postsByDate = result.data;`

Comment: Why not convert the value to a date and then use the data parts?

Answer (score 0):

You are sticking your data in a local variable but then trying to access it from a property on $scope. You can fix it by changing the forEach to access the array from the correct place:

```
$scope.getPostsDate = function() {
    PostsService.getPosts($scope.token).then(function(result) {
        var postsByDate = result.data;
        //postsByDate is not on $scope, it is local, so just access it directly
        angular.forEach(postsByDate, function(value, key) {
            var oldDate = value.event_date;
            value.newDate = oldDate.slice(0, 10);
            console.log('date' +value.newDate);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I fixed this before posting here, I forgot to update the post. But thanks